# JSDoc, DocDash, @typedef does not appear in table of contents

Tags: javascript, documentation, typedef, jsdoc

I am trying to get my table of contents to list constants, functions, and typedefs for each of my modules, allowing for searchable documentation.  I am using DocDash with JSDoc.  JSDoc appears to be recognizing the types nicely, but the type defs do not appear in the table of contents.

Code definition example

```
/**
 * @typedef ActivityOptions
 * @memberof module:CardSession
 * @property {boolean} quiz ...yada yada...truncated.
 */

//Using JSON Schema compatible constant as the type definition.
export const ActivityOptions = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        quiz: {type: 'boolean'},
        canSkip: {type: 'boolean'},
        repeat: {type: 'boolean'},
        timeLimit: {type:'number'},//in percent
        questionLimit: {type: 'number'},
        passingProps: PassingProps,
        prereq: {
            type: 'array',
            members: {type: 'string'}
        },
        completion: {
            type: 'array',
            members: {type: 'string'}
        },
        rules: EnumActivityRules
    },
    required: ['quiz','canSkip','repeat','passingProps','prereq','completion','rules'],
    additionalProperties: false
};
```

Here is my jsdoc.json.  Could provide full file if relevant, but here is the 'docdash' member only.

```
{
    "docdash": {
        "static": true,
        "sort": true,
        "sectionOrder": [
            "Classes",
            "Tutorials",
            "Modules",
            "Externals",
            "Events",
            "Namespaces",
            "Mixins",
            "Interfaces"
        ],
        "disqus": "musicards.io",
        "search": true,
        "commonNav": false,
        "collapse": true,
        "wrap": false,
        "typedefs": true,
        "navLevel": 1,
        "private": true,
        "removeQuotes": "none",
        "scripts": [],
        "ShortenTypes": false,
        "scopeInOutputPath": true,
        "nameInOutputPath": true,
        "versionInOutputPath": true
  }
    
}
```

[image: screenshot]
On the menu, the typedef is correctly listed in the module, but it is buried under all the functions and not shown in the table of contents.  Furthermore, the quick search bar does not reveal the typedef as a result because of this.

[image: screenshot]